# angular js: accessing $scope from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

There are several questions like this in stackoverflow. I know. Tried all the answers, but still no luck.
My html :

```
    <div class="headline" id="headline-game">
        {{gameContent.headline}}
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
    var country = $("#headline-game").scope().headline;
    alert(country);
```

But I got undefined, instead of my scope. Can anyone help me? I don't wanna change the scope, just accessing it.

Comment: jQuery has no `scope()` function.

Answer (score 13):

Angular adds a global `angular` variable to your window.

So you can do something like this:

```
angular.element("#headline-game").scope().gameContent.headline;
```

Comment: I also did that before. got an error said:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headline' of undefined

Comment: do you have gameContent object? try just this angular.element("#headline-game").scope() on the console and examine the available properties

Comment: @hjgrace yes I do. I tried that. but maybe because I tried in console after the $scope loaded. and the jquery function was called before it was loaded. do u have an idea to solve it?

Comment: @catwoman one way is to break execution, with breakpoinst in chrome console or write "debugger;" (without quotes) after you set your gameContent variable on your controller so it breaks execution and then you can inspect your scope in the console.

Comment: @ishwr in this case using the ng-if on the element, ensures that $scope is loaded.

Comment: it does not works when  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by the order in which the plugins are initialized.

1. jQuery
2. AngularJS

So accessing `scope()` in a jQuery script on document load will result in undefined, since jQuery is run **before** Angular.

The solution to this is to let AngularJS execute jQuery once it is ready, using **directives**.

Example :

#### Controller

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                customheadline: "@"
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                var country = scope.customheadline;
                alert(country);
            }
        }
    });
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="headline" id="headline-game" my-directive customheadline="{{ gameContent.headline }}">
    {{gameContent.headline}}
</div>
```

Comment: What did work for me is:
    app.directive("myDirective", function() {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: {
                    customheadline: "@"
                },
                link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                    var country = element.scope().customheadline;
                    alert(country);
                }
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var country = $("#headline-game").scope().gameContent.headline;
alert(country);
```

Comment: I did, but because of scope().gameContent is undefined I got an error said:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headline' of undefined

Comment: So I think you are trying to access it before it defines.

Comment: you are right. maybe i tried to access it before it defines, eventhough i wrote it inside $(function () {}) Then what is the right way to do it?

Comment: You need to use that jquery piece of code inside Angular something like in a $scope.$watch("gameContent.headline") to make sure you have the scope and value in place.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the model value is return from a $http request.

In the controller you have 3 functions:

```
function getGameContentSuccessCallback(){
   doSuccessCallback();
}

function getGameContentErrorCallback(){
  doSth()
}

function getGameContent(){
  GameContentService.GetGameContent(submitData,getGameContentSuccessCallback,getGameContentErrorCallback)

}
```

then you define doSuccessCallback in jQuery

```
var doSuccessCallback = function(){   
   var country  = angular.element("#headline-game").scope().gameContent.headline;   
   alert(country );   
}
```