# Using onclick in ngrepeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to use `onclick` event within `ng-repeat` to call a jQuery function?

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td><a onclick="loadEditModal(item.Id)">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function = loadEditModal() {
    alert("yes");
};
```

Comment: check this, I hope it may help [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877008/angular-js-accessing-scope-from-jquery)

Comment: check this related issue , I hope it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877008/angular-js-accessing-scope-from-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You should use angularjs `ng-click` for that: (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td><a ng-click="loadEditModal(item.Id)">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**
To call a function from an external js file, (which is not a good practice!) you can use ng-click as above, and then from the angularjs controller's function, call the external method like this:

```
loadEditModal () {

    var modalFunc = window["loadEditModal"];
    modalFunc();

};
```

Comment: I don't want to use ng-click

Comment: I need to trigger the jquery function

Comment: Ok , I edited with another solution , but this is a really bad practice

Answer (score 0):

I guess you not have to use `ng-click`.

In that case you can directly call Jquery/JavaScript function from `on-click`, but there is one problem that you cannot bind `item.id` value in that function. So you have to pass value into `loadEditModal` function with `{{ }}` format:

```
<a onclick="loadEditModal({{item.Id}})">Edit</a>

<script>
  function loadEditModal (id) {
  console.log(id)
}
</script>
```